# How to find position of bottommost line of text in HTML document as rendered by browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am displaying some HTML in a web view in my app (it's a `WKWebView` in an iOS app, but that part is irrelevant as the same HTML/JavaScript is used on multiple platforms). External to the web view is a way the user can say "next page". In response to this, I want to scroll the document by one screen-height. That's pretty simple and I can easily do that and it works great.

The problem is that if the last visible line is split between one "page" and the next, you see the top half of the line on one page and the bottom half on the next page. This is difficult to read. So ideally, I'd like to iterate through the HTML document by rendered line and find the last line that is fully visible, then scroll so that the line after that is at the top of the screen. Naturally this assumes no tables, images, floating elements etc. to complicate the definition of what constitutes a "line", but I can deal with that if I can solve the simpler case first.

I can iterate over paragraphs in the DOM and finding bounding rectangles for those, but don't see an obvious way to break it down any further than that. I can imagine a solution in which I wrap each word in my HTML with a `<span>`, then iterate over those looking at position and height to determine where the bottom of the screen is, but that sounds pretty inefficient.

I have control over the CSS and JavaScript in my displayed document (all documents use the same CSS and JavaScript, which is added at runtime) and can make modifications to the HTML at runtime if I have to, but performance is obviously an issue so I don't want to do a lot of monkeying around with the HTML I'm displaying if I don't have to.

I strongly suspect this is impossible without adding `<span>` tags as described above. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go through all paragraphs (mainly `p`, but other tags could be considered as well), get their top offset, and find the last one that still has its top offset in the viewable range. This should be the top paragraph after performing the controlled "page down" operation.

Here is some code relying on `jQuery` to return the offset of that element:

```
function offsetForNextPage() {
    var bottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var result = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() * 0.75; // minimum scroll amount
    $('p, span, div').each(function(idx) {
        if ($(this).offset().top >= bottom) {
            return false;
        }
        result = Math.max($(this).offset().top, result);
    });
    return result;
}
```

You can of course add the tags you want to include in this calculation. Note that if no suitable element is found, or it would result into an offset that is considered too small, a minimum offset is returned instead. The above function has set that minimum to the current offset plus 75% of the viewport height.

Here is how it would look if the space key would trigger a page-down:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: offsetForNextPage()
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cy275uku/1/).

NB: for `$(window).height()` to give correct values, you must have a valid document type declaration at the start of the `html` page, like:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: That may be the best I can do. I'd have to make it fail gracefully if the paragraph at the top of the  current page spanned multiple pages. I wonder if I could look at line height for the font used in that paragraph. I'd have to figure out where to best find that...

Comment: I have updated the code and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cy275uku/1/) to use a minimum scrolling distance.This will prevent undesired behaviour when there is a large paragraph involved. I have set that minimum to 75% of the window height, but you can set it as you wish.

Comment: I ended up using something very similar to this. I happen to have all my paragraphs and paragraph-like things wrapped in `<div>` tags, as I have some control over the HTML. So my search for paragraph-like elements was simple. Once I find the paragrpah that spans the bottom of the screen, I use `getComputedStyle()` to get the `line-height`, then add that to the div's `offsetTop` until I get as close to the bottom of the screen as I can without going past. I throw in a test to make sure I didn't just end up at the same y-coordinate I'm already at, and if so, I use 95% of the screen height.